# Flow Control with exception

Tags: java, exception, runtime

When I run the following code, there are two result.

```
 package scjp;

    public class ExceptionTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ExceptionTest test = new ExceptionTest();
            test.method1();
        }

        public void method1() {
            try {
                System.out.println("Try Block");

                if (!true) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException();
                }
            }finally {
                System.out.println("Finally Block");
            }
        }
    }
```

One result is

```
Try Block
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException
    at scjp.ExceptionTest.method1(ExceptionTest.java:17)
    at scjp.ExceptionTest.main(ExceptionTest.java:7)
Finally Block
```

and the other,

```
Try Block
Finally Block
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException
    at scjp.ExceptionTest.method1(ExceptionTest.java:17)
    at scjp.ExceptionTest.main(ExceptionTest.java:7)
```

Each time I am running the above code, the answer is changing. In my understanding, it should always be same result. Can you help me something???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The system error output stream (the stack trace above, likely in red in your console) is different than the system output stream (your `System.out.println()` statements).  Hence error messages can be out of sync with normal console output since both streams write to the console, but independently of each other.  The differences are as follows:

```
System.out.println("Some text");
```

prints to the out stream

```
System.err.println("Error occurred!");
```

prints to the error stream

The two can get intermixed when outputting to the same console.

Answer (score 0):

The exception stacktrace is not printed on the same outputstrean (it is printed on System.err) and System.err and System.out are not synchronized.

To always have the same output you could print your messages on System.err rather than on System.out.